# How to apply "display: none" on div on click event while using div's class

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have some script for bootstrap dropdown, I want to apply "display: none" style on my div by script I have tried the following script

```
var modal = document.getElementById('black');

  window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }
 }


$('.drp').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
   modal.style.display = "none";
});

$('.drp').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
 modal.style.display = "block";
});

$('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown a').on('click', function (event) {
$(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
 modal.style.display = "block";
});
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
 if (!$('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').is(e.target) && $('li.dropdown.mega- dropdown').has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.open').has(e.target).length === 0)  {
     $('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').removeClass('open');
}
});
```

I want to apply (modal.style.display = "block";) on (li.dropdown.mega-dropdown)'s click event.

Comment: show us everything you have done mate

Comment: my fiddle is this https://jsfiddle.net/dami_012/L7yz6v3j/

Comment: i want to display none background black screen on dr2 dropdown again click like dropdown menu

Comment: Is there any one help me for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done my self, I m missing my if condition in script, here is my right answer .     [DEMO][1]

```
                [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/dami_012/L7yz6v3j/3/
```